# How to pass data from custom TexInput component to main Login component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm having problems when authenticating users in my application, I have a component called MaterialMessageTextBox11 where inside it has the `<TextInput>`, so far I managed to get the value that the user types in the input and save it in a state but I need to access this value (which would be the login and password) in the main component (which would be **Login.js**) to then be able to validate the data entered, however I am unable to pass either through ownership or navigation, thanks for the help!

***CODE:***

Login.js:

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: null,
      password: null,
      isLogged: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLogged) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Dashboard");
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <MaterialMessageTextbox11
          style={styles.materialMessageTextbox11}
          handlePress={this.setMyText}


        />

        <MaterialMessageTextbox12
          style={styles.materialMessageTextbox12}

        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

MaterialMessageTextBox11,js (Custom TextInput Component):

```
function MaterialMessageTextbox11(props) {

let [username, setUsername] = useState("");


  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, props.style]}>
      <TextInput
        placeholder=""
        onChangeText={(value) => setUsername(value)}

        style={[
          styles.inputStyle,
          {
            borderBottomColor: props.error
              ? "red"
              : props.success
              ? "green"
              : "#D9D5DC",
          },
        ]}
      ></TextInput>

    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make and use `Custom Textinput`, you can set it as follows.

**Textinput.js**

```js
 <TextInput 
      value={value} 
      onChangeText={onChange}
      placeholder=""
      style={[
          styles.inputStyle,
          {
            borderBottomColor: props.error
              ? "red"
              : props.success
              ? "green"
              : "#D9D5DC",
          },
        ]} />
```

**Usage**

```js
        <MaterialMessageTextbox11
          style={styles.materialMessageTextbox11}
          value={this.state.username}
          onChange={input => this.setState({ username: input })}
        />
```

Comment: Should i pass onChange and value as props inside of custom textinput component?